# Reading and writing files in Cyrillic in c++

Tags: c++, file, input, wofstream, wifstream

I have to first read a file in Cyrillic, then randomly pick random number of lines and write modified text to a different file. No problem with Latin letter, but I run into a problem with Cyrillic text, because I get some rubbish. So this is how I tried to do the thing.

Say, file `input.txt` is

```
ааааааа
ббббббб
ввввввв
```

I have to read it, and put every line into a vector:

```
vector<wstring> inputVector;
wstring inputString, result;
wifstream inputStream;
inputStream.open("input.txt");
while(!inputStream.eof())
{
    getline(inputStream, inputString);              
    inputVector.push_back(inputString);
}
inputStream.close();    

srand(time(NULL));
int numLines = rand() % inputVector.size();
for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
{
    int randomLine = rand() % inputVector.size();
    result += inputVector[randomLine];
}

wofstream resultStream;
resultStream.open("result.txt");
resultStream << result;
resultStream.close();
```

So how can I do work with Cyrillic so it produces readable things, not just symbols?

Comment: What do you mean `readable things, not just symbols?`  What does `result.txt` look like, and what do you _want_ it to look like?

Comment: I would like to get smth like аааааааввввввв, but get  2A =04  ?@> (smth like that). i do not know how to read Cyrillic, and how to write Cyrillic back.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: I used Unicode for file encoding. Also tried _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); - works for console output, but I still get rubbish in the file.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  After you open `resultStream`, try the lines `resultStream.write("\xFEFF", 4);` or `resultStream.write("\xFFFE", 4);` before outputting `result` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you saw something like ■a a a a a a a 1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦ 2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦ printed to the console, it appears that `input.txt` is encoded in a UTF-16 encoding, probably UTF-16 LE + [BOM](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can use your original code if you change the encoding of the file to UTF-8.

The reason for using UTF-8 is that, regardless of the char type of the file stream, `basic_fstream`'s underlying `basic_filebuf` uses a `codecvt` object to convert a stream of `char` objects to/from a stream of objects of the char type; i.e. when reading, the `char` stream that is read from the file is converted to a `wchar_t` stream, but when writing, a `wchar_t` stream is converted to a `char` stream that is then written to the file. In the case of `std::wifstream`, the `codecvt` object is an instance of the standard `std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>`, which generally converts UTF-8 to UCS-16.

As explained on [the MSDN documentation page for `basic_filebuf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzf8k3z8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Objects of type **basic_filebuf** are created with an internal buffer of type char * regardless of the **char_type** specified by the type parameter *Elem*. This means that a Unicode string (containing wchar_t characters) will be converted to an ANSI string (containing char characters) before it is written to the internal buffer.

Similarly, when reading a Unicode string (containing `wchar_t` characters), the `basic_filebuf` converts the ANSI string read from the file to the `wchar_t` string returned to `getline` and other read operations.

If you change the encoding of `input.txt` to UTF-8, your original program should work correctly.

For reference, this works for me:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<wstring> inputVector;
    wstring inputString, result;
    wifstream inputStream;
    inputStream.open("input.txt");
    while(!inputStream.eof())
    {
        getline(inputStream, inputString);
        inputVector.push_back(inputString);
    }
    inputStream.close();

    srand(time(NULL));
    int numLines = rand() % inputVector.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        int randomLine = rand() % inputVector.size();
        result += inputVector[randomLine];
    }

    wofstream resultStream;
    resultStream.open("result.txt");
    resultStream << result;
    resultStream.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the encoding of `result.txt` will also be UTF-8 (generally).

Comment: Works like a charm now! Thanks for help and MSDN link!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use `wifstream` -- are you confident that your file consists of a sequence of (system-dependent) *wide characters*? Almost certainly that is not the case. (Most notably because the system's wide character set isn't actually definite outside the scope of a C++ program).

Instead, just read the input byte stream as it is and echo it accordingly:

```
std::ifstream infile(thefile);
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> input;

while (std::getline(infile, line))   // like this!!
{
  input.push_back(line);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: Tried to read file that way, and then output to the console looks like this:
 ■a a a a a a a
 1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦1♦
 2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦2♦

Comment: Make sure that your environment is set to the correct locale that corresponds to the file's encoding, and that your terminal supports the required character set.